# Drawing rect on a frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to detect pixels that have value higher than let say `cvScalar(200,200,200)`.

And after that I want to draw a rectangle on all those pixel using `cv::rectangle`. Can anybody help me how to do this?

see this figure below to it exactly what I want to do. 
![ image ] : http://technical-recipes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/glove3.jpg

Comment: I don't exactly understand how you want to place your rectangle, how should your rectangle look like if one pixel out of two has a value higher than (200,200,200) ?

Comment: Or do you want to create a rectangle surrounding all the points having a value higher than (200,200,200) ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solve your problem:

1. I found all needed pixels using `inRange`.
2. After this, I found all contours.
3. Then I constructed big contour from all these contours.
4. Finally, found `boundingRect` of this big contour and draw it.

Here's a c++ code:

```
Mat src = imread("image.jpg"), mask;

const Scalar minScalar = Scalar(200, 200, 200);
const Scalar maxScalar = Scalar(255, 255, 255);

inRange(src, minScalar, maxScalar, mask);

vector<vector<Point2i> > contours;

findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

vector<Point2i> bigContour;
for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
    {
        bigContour.push_back(contours[i][j]);
    }
}

Rect rect = boundingRect(bigContour);
rectangle(src, rect, Scalar(255, 0, 255));

imshow("Image", src);
waitKey();
```

Comment: thanks Astor, but this works only for one frame, I need to do this on video, a live streaming, even I thread this it wouldn't work

Comment: it just makes my streaming to slow and 2.it's exactly what I meant, I added a image to my question in which tow part with the same color are selected. thanks for you help again